# Empty file (0bytes) recorded by mediarecorder

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I am trying to record a video in background through Service but my code creates and empty video file everytime and not returning any error as well.

Below is my Service class:

```
public class BackGroundVideoRecorder extends Service implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "BackGroundVideoRecorder";

    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = null;
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private Camera camera = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        // Create new SurfaceView, set its size to 1x1, move it to the top left corner and set this service as a callback
        windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        surfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                1, 1,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
        windowManager.addView(surfaceView, layoutParams);
        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

        camera = Camera.open(1);
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        camera.unlock();

        //mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(320, 480);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
        String out = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Output/" +
                DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_kk-mm-ss", new Date().getTime()) +
                ".mp4";

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Output");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("FolderName", "failed to create directory");
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(30000);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mediaFile);
        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());

        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaRecorder.start();

    }

    // Stop recording and remove SurfaceView
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        if (camera != null) {
            camera.lock();
            camera.release();
        }

        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.reset();
            mediaRecorder.release();
        }



        if (windowManager != null) {
            windowManager.removeView(surfaceView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Please suggest any solution or error if you found.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `prepare()` throwing an exception?

Comment: No, no any exception caught.

Comment: Anything relevant in the logcat? Messages from the mediaplayer, for instance?

Comment: Nothing like that.